# Error when trying to get rid of OpenID in application UndefinedError: 'app.forms.RegistrationForm object' has no attribute 'openid'

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, openid

I am trying to get rid of OpenID and make a standard username/password login and keep getting the following OpenID error when trying to goto my index/login page.

Error found in Flask

```
UndefinedError: 'app.forms.RegistrationForm object' has no attribute 'openid'
```

Error in debugger from jinja

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'app.forms.RegistrationForm object' has no attribute 'openid'
Traceback (most recent call last)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app

response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app

response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request

rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request

return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_openid.py", line 500, in decorated

return f(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/views.py", line 104, in login

form=form)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template

context, ctx.app)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render

rv = template.render(context)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render

return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception

reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/login.html", line 2, in top-level template code

{% extends "base.html" %}

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/base.html", line 66, in top-level template code

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/app/templates/login.html", line 39, in block "content"

File "/home/jsnyder10/Documents/45/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr

return getattr(obj, attribute)

UndefinedError: 'app.forms.RegistrationForm object' has no attribute 'openid'
```

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

Here is the code for login.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% include 'flash.html' %}
<div class="well">
    <h3>{{ _('Please Sign In') }}</h3>
    <form class="form" action="" method="post" name="login">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <label class="control-label">{{ _('Enter your UserID here:') }}</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{ form.username(size=80, class="span4") }}
                {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                    <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Code for index.html

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ _('Hi, %(nickname)s!', nickname=g.user.nickname) }}</h1>
{% include 'flash.html' %}
<div class="well">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="control-group{% if form.post.errors %} error{% endif %}">
            <label class="control-label" for="post">{{ _('Say something:') }}</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{ form.post(size=30, maxlength=140) }}
                {% for error in form.post.errors %}
                    <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ _('Post!') }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% for post in posts.items %}
    {% include 'post.html' %}
{% endfor %}
<ul class="pager">
    {% if posts.has_prev %}
    <li class="previous"><a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.prev_num) }}">{{ _('Newer posts') }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="previous disabled"><a href="#">{{ _('Newer posts') }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if posts.has_next %}
    <li class="next"><a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.next_num) }}">{{ _('Older posts') }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="next disabled"><a href="#">{{ _('Older posts') }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

code for views.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request, \
g, jsonify
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user,     login_required
from flask_sqlalchemy import get_debug_queries
from flask_babel import gettext
from datetime import datetime
from guess_language import guessLanguage
from app import app, db, lm, oid, babel
from .forms import LoginForm, EditForm, PostForm, SearchForm, RegistrationForm
from .models import User, Post
from .emails import follower_notification
from .translate import microsoft_translate
from config import POSTS_PER_PAGE, MAX_SEARCH_RESULTS, LANGUAGES, \
DATABASE_QUERY_TIMEOUT

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index(page=1):
form = PostForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    language = guessLanguage(form.post.data)
    if language == 'UNKNOWN' or len(language) > 5:
        language = ''
    post = Post(body=form.post.data, timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                author=g.user, language=language)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(gettext('Your post is now live!'))
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
posts = g.user.followed_posts().paginate(page, POSTS_PER_PAGE, False)
return render_template('index.html',
                       title='Home',
                       form=form,
                       posts=posts)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@oid.loginhandler
def login():
if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
form = RegistrationForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    session['remember_me'] = form.remember_me.data
return render_template('login.html',
                       title='Sign In',
                       form=form)
```

Can someone explain what app.forms.RegistrationForm is actually doing? It's not in my code anywhere and even when I run my code in python I can't get app.forms to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In my login.html template it had code that referenced it and even though it was disabled using the brackets in html, Flask kept reading it anyways and threw out an error.

Lesson to self, Flask does not ignore code even if bracketed out and will crash if there are errors in ignored html code.